# How to set xticks at specific position?

Tags: matplotlib

In the following plot I want to use only 3 values of xticks, keeping zero at the center? How Can I do that? My xticks values are not organized along x-axis.

```
`s= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
E=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    E_val =-2*np.cos(s[i])
    E.append(E_val)

E= np.array(E)
print(E)
plt.plot(s,E,marker='.')
plt.xticks(np.arange(3), [r'$-\pi$', r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])`
```

[image]

Comment: You place the ticks at positions `0,1,2`. Seems you would rather want to place them at `-pi, 0, pi`?

Comment: I want to place them in such a way that -pi is at left corner of x-axis, pi is at right corner and zero should be at the center

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Now I tried this and got desired result plt.xticks([s[0],s[int(len(s)/2)], s[-1]], [r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
E=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
   E_val =-2*np.cos(s[i])
   E.append(E_val)

E= np.array(E)
print(E)
plt.plot(s,E,marker='.')

plt.xticks(np.arange(-math.pi,math.pi+1,math.pi), [r'$-\pi$', r'$0$', r'$\pi$' ])

plt.show()
```